# shifting pandas series for only some entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that has a `Time` Series (made up of strings) with some missing information:

```
# Generate a toy dataframe:
import pandas as pd
data = {'Time': ['0'+str(i)+':15:45' for i in range(10)]}
data['Time'][4] = 'unknown'
data['Time'][8] = 'unknown'

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df
       Time
0  00:15:45
1  01:15:45
2  02:15:45
3  03:15:45
4   unknown
5  05:15:45
6  06:15:45
7  07:15:45
8   unknown
9  09:15:45
```

I would like the `unknown` entries to match the entry above, resulting in this dataframe:

```
# desired_df
       Time
0  00:15:45
1  01:15:45
2  02:15:45
3  03:15:45
4  03:15:45
5  05:15:45
6  06:15:45
7  07:15:45
8  07:15:45
9  09:15:45
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intent on working with a time series data. I would recommend converting it to a time series, and then forward filling the blanks

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Time': ['0'+str(i)+':15:45' for i in range(10)]}
data['Time'][4] = 'unknown'
data['Time'][8] = 'unknown'
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, errors = 'coerce')
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

However, if you are getting this data from a `csv` file or something where you use `pandas.read_*` function you should use the `na_values` argument in those functions to specify `unknown` as a NA value

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', na_values = 'unknown')
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

you can also pass a list instead of the string, and it adds the words passed to already existing list of NA values

However, if you want to keep the column a string, I would recommend just doing a find and replace

```
df.Time = np.where(df.Time == 'unknown', df.Time.shift(),df.Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be using pandas' `shift`, creating a new column with the data in `Time` shifted by one, and dropping it. But there may be a cleaner way to achieve this:

```
# Create new column with the shifted time data
df['Time2'] = df['Time'].shift()
# Replace the data in Time with the data in your new column where necessary
df.loc[df['Time'] == 'unknown', 'Time'] = df.loc[df['Time'] == 'unknown', 'Time2']
# Drop your new column
df = df.drop('Time2', axis=1)

print(df)

       Time
0  00:15:45
1  01:15:45
2  02:15:45
3  03:15:45
4  03:15:45
5  05:15:45
6  06:15:45
7  07:15:45
8  07:15:45
9  09:15:45
```

EDIT: as pointed out by Zero, the new column step can be skipped altogether:

```
df.loc[df['Time'] == 'unknown', 'Time'] = df['Time'].shift()
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['Time'] == 'unknown', 'Time'] = df['Time'].shift()` should do.

Comment: True, @Zero that is a nicer way to do it

Comment: `df['Time'].replace(to_replace = 'unknown', method = 'ffill', inplace = True)` is another option.